# Javascript exact word but not its negative

Tags: javascript

I need to read a comma delimitter string -- but catch the logic if it contains its negative or not.

```
let robots = "index, nofollow";
```

if I do a check to see if follow is in the string - it should come up false.

```
robots.includes("follow")
```

should return false - but this will register as true how do I avoid this?

Comment: The [`String.includes` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) may be of interest. All it does is checks if the string is included anywhere in the string under test, and `"follow"` is part of the string `"nofollow"`. You *could* use a regex, but if you have an explicitly comma-separated list, splitting, trimming, and checking the *array* is a cleaner approach.

Comment: What is the desired output? Just the `index` because `nofollow` starts with `no`? Please [edit] the question to add desired output.

Comment: Sure - that's why I've proposed this question to the board

Comment: well -- it could be -- index, follow --- or nofollow, index -- or noindex, nofollow --

Comment: @TheOldCounty Please add the desired output. Not sure if the `includes` questions is a [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) or the real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex this way to match the whole word  only

```js
let robots = "index, nofollow";
let regex = /\bfollow\b/

console.log(regex.test(robots))
```

or

```js
let robots = "index, nofollow";
let string = 'follow'
let regex = new RegExp(`\\b${string}\\b`)
console.log(regex.test(robots))
```

\b is called a word boundary. It matches at the start or the end of a word

Comment: this looks like a viable solution -- what does the b do?

Comment: word boundaries - https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: the \b encasement matches the start and end of the word. So only the exact word is matched as true

Comment: How would I put this into a function to test easier?    isToggled(toggle, string){
    return /\b$toggle\b/.test(string);
  }  -- isn't working

Comment: let re = new RegExp(`\\b${toggle}\\b`, 'gi');
    
    return re.test(string);

Comment: Yes you are right and I have made the update to the answer with RegExp constructor, but you can use g and i if you want non-case-sensitive and complete match

Answer (score 0):

Split and test the array

```js
let robots = "index, nofollow";

console.log(robots.split(',').map(word=>word.trim()).includes("follow"))
```

or if you can trust the whitespace

```js
let robots = "index, nofollow";

console.log(robots.split(', ').includes("follow"))
```

Comment: what if nofollow is at the start of the string?

Comment: @TheOldCounty Solutions are easily tested either via a snippet here, or in a JS console.

Comment: @TheOldCounty my code does not care where follow or no follow is

Comment: Array.Includes is position agnostic

Comment: ok - I'll check it - but wasn't sure - if your split(", ") would effect it

Comment: If you are worried, use first version which removes whitespace

Comment: well -- it could be -- index, follow --- or nofollow, index -- or noindex, nofollow

Comment: I meant if you are nervous where the whitesoace is or newlines, not the  order - my code does not care about order

Comment: @TheOldCounty You can copy the code to the JS console and *test it*.

Comment: well yes - but I thought it best to ask first here

Comment: @TheOldCounty Why? I'm not criticizing, I'm trying to understand. It's literally seconds to just try out scenarios and see if it works for you.